# error: declaration of instance variables in the interface is deprecated [-Werror,-Wobjc-interface-ivars]

Tags: objective-c

I just cloned a project from github and I went to build it and I ran into this error over and over again. Any idea what the problem is?

Here is some of my error output and some of the code that causes the error:

NOTE:
_indexSetFlags and _internal are the variables that are causing the error in this code example

```
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>
#import <Foundation/NSRange.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface NSIndexSet : NSObject <NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, NSSecureCoding> {
    @protected   // all instance variables are private
    struct {
        NSUInteger _isEmpty:1;
        NSUInteger _hasSingleRange:1;
        NSUInteger _cacheValid:1;
        NSUInteger _reservedArrayBinderController:29;
    } _indexSetFlags;
    union {
        struct {
            NSRange _range;
        } _singleRange;
        struct {
            void * _data;
            void *_reserved;
        } _multipleRanges;
    } _internal;
}
```

ERROR OUTPUT:

> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAutoreleasePool.h:14:11:
> error: declaration of instance variables in the
> interface is deprecated [-Werror,-Wobjc-interface-ivars]
> void        *_reserved2;
>
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:543:9:
> error: declaration of instance variables in the interface is
> deprecated [-Werror,-Wobjc-interface-ivars]
> int numBytes;
> ^ /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:545:9:
> error: declaration of instance variables in the interface is
> deprecated [-Werror,-Wobjc-interface-ivars]
> int _unused;
> ^
>
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSNotification.h:39:11:
> error: declaration of instance variables in the
> interface is deprecated [-Werror,-Wobjc-interface-ivars]
> void *_impl;
> ^
>
> fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=] 20
> errors generated.
>
> The following build commands failed:  CompileC
> /Users/bananaman123/Desktop/eecs481/hw6/wz_build/lib/sdl/warzone2100.build/Debug/sdl-backend.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/cocoa_wz_menus.o lib/sdl/cocoa_wz_menus.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++
> com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (1 failure)

I left out a lot of the error output, but all of the error messages contain "error: declaration of instance variables in the interface is deprecated [-Werror,-Wobjc-interface-ivars]"

Comment: This doesn't appear to be c++

Comment: The error message is very precise. If you absolutely can't change the code accordingly, remove the compiler switches that make this an error, as indicated.

Comment: you are possibly one project setting step ahead and need to start again step by step. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [repository](https://github.com/Warzone2100/warzone2100) README.md suggests at the very last line, go and read

https://github.com/Warzone2100/warzone2100/blob/master/macosx/README.md

then go step by step and fulfil the requirements.
It's mainly written in C++ and so it needs according treatment.

You need CMake 3.15+,
find it here https://cmake.org/download/#latest

also Gettext via Homebrew

and Asciidoctor via Homebrew as well.

As you obviously use OSX 10.15+ you don't need GCC, Xcode > 11 is fine.

Your errors go back to a bogus project setup.
`NSIndexSet` is a class that belongs to Foundation Framework. *Usually* nothing to repair for you in this code. Quite sure this comes up because Objective-C++ is assumed to work which is a simple way to include C++ into your Xcode project. Read more about working with `.mm` files if you want to change the way it is added to your project because..

Somewhere between the lines in the Readme.md is also written..

> "Run CMake to generate the Xcode project"

Comment: I have all the tools installed, but looking through the output, I see a few red flags. First, it says that gettext is not found. The exact output is:
-- Looking for gettext
-- Looking for gettext - not found
-- Looking for iconv
-- Looking for iconv - not found
-- Looking for strlcat
-- Looking for strlcat - found
...

Why isn't it finding gettext? when I type gettext --version, I can clearly see that version 0.21 is installed.

Comment: homebrew is like a postcard from the past. never could keep it productive in 15 years of coding. each project the same troubles. Btw gettext is a text localization (translation keeper) tool, sounds huge but is a tiny feature compared to apple frameworks. well my comment doesn't help you. But maybe you ask under tag <homebrew> or <brew> here in SO with some error logs..